# Unable to mount a developer disk image. iOS 15.4.1 - Xcode 13.3.1 (13E500a)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

iOS: 15.4.1 , Xcode: 13.3.1 (13E500a), macOS: 12.3.1 (21E258)

Hi, I was originally trying to remote debug in Terminal by:

```
idevicedebugserverproxy -d 9999
```

then in a lldb session:

```
process connect connect://localhost:9999
```

but lldb returned:

```
error: failed to get reply to handshake packet
```

and idevicedebugserverproxy returned:

```
main: Waiting for connection on local port 9999
main: Handling new client connection...
main: Waiting for connection on local port 9999
connection_handler: client_fd = 4
Could not start debugserver on device!
Please make sure to mount a developer disk image first.
```

I did some research saying that build an app with Xcode would automatically mount the disk image for us, so I simply built and ran the default "hello world!" app on the phone, but still receive above errors. I also rebooted the phone many times with no luck.

So I decided to mount it manually with the latest developer disk image 15.4 by:

```
ideviceimagemounter /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/15.4/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/15.4/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature
```

but kept receiving this error:

```
done.
Mounting...
Error: ImageMountFailed
```

I'm assuming developer disk image have to match the phone's version, but I can't find the 15.4.1 version.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by uninstalling libplist, usbmuxd, libimobiledevice, ideviceinstaller from brew and manually build the latest version from GitHub.

```
done.
Mounting...
Done.
Status: Complete
```